# XCode: When i have a library that is using C++, why must I use Compile As Objective C++ when used in another project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've created this static library that uses a mix of Objective C and C++, lets say it comes out as lib.a.

When I use it in another new XCode project, how come I must set "Compile Sources As" Objective C++?

I'm not understanding why my new project needs to be compiled as Objective C++ when the Library has already been compiled.

So when I compile I get these errors if I don't set it to Objective C++:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "___dynamic_cast", referenced from:
>         CommSocket::Handover(CCommSocket&) in lib.a(CommSock.o)
>         CSocketComm::Handover(CCommSocket&) in lib.a(SocketComm.o)

Comment: Can you provide some code as to how you use the library in your other project?

Comment: Basically the project uses all objective-C and I'm calling it using objective-c syntax. Only inside the library do we use any C, C++ codes.

Comment: As far as I know, the "Compile Sources As" option doesn't affect linking, which is why I am somewhat confused. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thats' what i'm confused as well.  Those error messages are with in the library, not from any code I've written from my new app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be probably fix it by adding `-lc++` to the "Other linker flags" section for your executable target to force the c++ runtime library to be linked.

Comment: You put me in a right direction, I needed to include the libc++.dylb and libstdc++.dylb into my Application that uses my library to make it work.  Now if I 'Compile sources as' According to file type. It will compile properly given my SDK header files are Objective C compatible.